# Ghost blog redirection issue

Tags: linux, bitnami, ghost-blog

I am trying to move a Linux machine from GCP to AWS and its completed. Inside that linux machine, Bitnami ghost blog stack is installed. But while trying to run it from the AWS environment, the **URL redirects back to old domain**.

I have changed the URL in `/opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/htdocs/config.production.json` and restarted but this is not working.
Also, I can not see any .htaccess file for redirection

Does any one know how to resolve this redirection issue ?

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Please review the Apache's configuration files (/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami) to confirm that there is not any rewrite line there that is causing the redirection to the old domains. You can also get more information about the redirection by running this command in the command line `curl -LI yournewdomain`

Comment: @JotaMartos It seems like there is a redirection. Please see the command's o/p https://docs.google.com/document/d/14uJFLRRge59t2z9RkE0GyH1518sOLHy0dpr2ECNVZME/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, that confirms my thoughts. The load balancer is redirecting to https://yournewdomain but then Apache redirects you back to the olddomain. Please take a look at the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf, /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/ghost-https-vhosts.conf and /opt/bitnami/apps/ghost/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf files